# can I use couple of JW Players on one page?

Tags: javascript, html, jwplayer

I'm trying to use couple of JW Players on one website. I need to place 48 of them actually, but it's only one visible. I assume it has something to do with the "container" parameter.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://video.captive-portal.com/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("container").setup({
        flashplayer: "http://video.captive-portal.com/player.swf",
        file: "http://content.captive-portal.com/campaigns/sky/videos/1/1.mp4",
        image: "http://content.captive-portal.com/campaigns/sky/videos/1/1.jpg",
        width: 480,
        height: 270
    });


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://video.captive-portal.com/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("container").setup({
        flashplayer: "http://video.captive-portal.com/player.swf",
        file: "http://content.captive-portal.com/campaigns/sky/videos/1/2.mp4",
        image: "http://content.captive-portal.com/campaigns/sky/videos/1/2.jpg",
        width: 480,
        height: 270
    });
</script>
```

If I change the "container" to anything else in case of the first one it displays just the second one so I assume the container holds the content (obviously). How can I modify this to have ability to play many videos on one page? I'm sure someone faced this problem as well. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

why not have a container on the outside and then create another div that holds the players you will just need to modify the css a Little to accommodate the players but other than that it should work something like this:

```
<Wrapper>
<maincontent>
<player1>
   `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://video.captive-portal.com/jwplayer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("container").setup({
    flashplayer: "http://video.captive-portal.com/player.swf",
    file: "http://content.captive-portal.com/campaigns/sky/videos/1/1.mp4",
    image: "http://content.captive-portal.com/campaigns/sky/videos/1/1.jpg",
    width: 480,
    height: 270
});
</div>

<player2>
   `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://video.captive-portal.com/jwplayer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("container").setup({
    flashplayer: "http://video.captive-portal.com/player.swf",
    file: "http://content.captive-portal.com/campaigns/sky/videos/1/1.mp4",
    image: "http://content.captive-portal.com/campaigns/sky/videos/1/1.jpg",
    width: 480,
    height: 270
});
</div>
</div> this is the end of the main content 
</div> this is the end of the Wrapper i changed container to wrapper so there are no conflicts
```

this is not wise best thing to do is make a video gallery so for example get 48 pictures use them as links to pages that you want associated with your videos and then when you click on the image you will have the video player starting

Comment: sorry, I don't know what do you mean here. Is it possible to include the code I placed in my question? this is the code which comes from the original jwplayer. I assume I can't modify it much apart from the links to the engine + video + image. The container is "inside" the actual script... code will embeded player be very helpful. thanks

Comment: depends on how would you want it setup ?? if you look at my last example i will edit it placing your code inside

Comment: unfortunately its not working. container (id) is required by jwplayer from what I can see and then "container" as a tag itself is necessary in player to display the video. Unfortaunately it doesn't work.

Comment: you dont need to change the container id they should stay the same as they was look at the example below that looks like it should work mine was a quick example

Answer (score 1):

You need to have 48 different DIV tags on your page, and each code will refer to a different div tag (with a ID or whatever). 
Also, you just need to fetch the jwplayer js file once in one script tag, and all the rest of the code can also be clubbed into one script tag.

This will essentially give you 48 players in one page, which isn't a very good idea. What you actually need to do, is to actually just load 48 images in a page, and use javascript to load the player with the corresponding video, only when the image is clicked.

Comment: That's how it works. It displays the image and after clicking it start streaming the video. It doesn't load it up instantly after the page is loaded.

Comment: @PiotrCiszewski thats nice. I hope the player load code doesn't do anything too heavy after showing the image, like drawing controls and attaching too many event handlers. 48 is a big number for all this.

Answer (score 1):

you want this for a mobile or tablet best thing to do is not load them on one page because it will use all your data best thing is probably my idea about the video gallery because then you can design it for mobiles better plus its less likely to run slow or eat the data up

Comment: this will all go through WiFi. The general idea is to have them all on one page because it works this way - you select the movie you like from the drop down list and it gives you examples of similar trailers you may be interested in... that's why they need to be all on one page. They don't play or even don't load up until clicked so it's not an issue I think.

Answer (score 0):

Just use different IDs for each instance of the player.

Quick demo code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://player.longtailvideo.com/jwplayer.js"></script>
        <title>Multiple</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="container"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer("container").setup({
            file: "http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.mp4",
            image: "http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.jpg",
            height: 300,
            width: 400,
            controlbar: "bottom"
             });
            </script>
            <div id="container2"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer("container2").setup({
            file: "http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.flv",
            image: "http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.jpg",
            height: 300,
            width: 400,
            controlbar: "bottom"
             });
            </script>
            <div id="container3"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer("container3").setup({
            file: "http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.mov",
            image: "http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.jpg",
            height: 300,
            width: 400,
            controlbar: "bottom"
             });
            </script>           
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks. Dos it work for you? I don't see any videos there. I checked on 3 browsers.

Comment: Np. Where are you running this? You should be able to copy and paste this code anywhere are it should work.